# How to sum datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, datetime, sum

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        s.LastName + ',' + s.FirstName as formattedName
       ,t.Date
       ,t.In1
       ,RIGHT (t.In1, 7) AS TineIn1
       ,RIGHT (t.Out1, 7) AS TimeOut1
       ,RIGHT (t.In2, 7) AS TimeIn2
       ,RIGHT (t.Out2, 7) AS TimeOut1
       ,RIGHT (t.In3, 7) AS TimeIn3
       ,RIGHT (t.Out3, 7) AS TimeOut3
       ,SUM (
              (t.In1-t.Out1)
             +(t.In2-t.Out2)
             +(t.In3-t.Out3)
             ) As WorkedHours

FROM   employee e

JOIN StudentID_EmpID SID
    ON e.EmpID = SID.EmpID
JOIN Student s
    ON SID.StudentID = s.StudentID
    AND s.StudentID = :parm_lb_StudenEE.studentID
JOIN Time t
    ON s.StudentID = t.StudentID
```

WorkedHours part does not work while trying to get total hour worked. I got following error message
 "Microsoft OLEDB provider for sQL Server : operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator"

my date format in database is In1 1/1/1900 8:30:00 AM and Out1 1/1/1900 12:30:00 PM and so on. that's the reason I have to do
 "RIGHT (t.In1, 7) AS TineIn1" 
just to get time as date here does not matter for me.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATEDIFF function to get the difference between two dates, and add those together:

```
 (DATEDIFF(second,t.IN1,t.Out1)
 +DATEDIFF(second,t.IN2,t.Out2)
 +DATEDIFF(second,t.IN3,t.Out3))/3600.0 AS WorkedHours
```

In this case, take the total seconds and divide by 3600.0 to return hours with decimal portion.  Other output options are mentioned in comments.

If any of the fields are `NULL` the result will be `NULL` so you can wrap them in `ISNULL()`:

```
 (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN1,t.Out1),0)
 +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN2,t.Out2),0)
 +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN3,t.Out3),0))/3600.0 AS WorkedHours
```

Comment: I don't think you really need `CAST(RIGHT(t.xxx,7) AS TIME)` in this case.  Also, you need to be aware of rounding effects caused by using `minutes`, depending on the accuracy of the data in those fields, using seconds may be better.  Additionally, the OP may want to have the result as a TIME datatype, so using `DATEADD(minute, <your formula>, 0)` would be better than `/60`.

Comment: It's in the error message : `operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator`

Comment: Thank you. but it says "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server : 'minutes' is not a recognized datediff option.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's not plural, 'minute' or 'second'.

Comment: Server error number: 003000
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server : 'seconds' is not a recognized datediff option.

Comment: Thank you looks like its working. there is no any error message at this time. but did not returned any value either

Comment: Are some of the fields `NULL`?

Comment: See updated answer, you'll need to wrap `ISNULL()` around each portion.